# Recursively decrease jquery animation speed for progress bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

For a progress bar, I am trying to gradually decrease the speed of a jquery animation on the width of a div.

The animate() runs while waiting for the server to respond, but since the delay is arbitrary, my idea is to set a default duration (average response time), and then gradually decrease the animation speed the longer it takes, so that it will never actually reach full width.

I believe I have seen the same effect in a few winforms progress bars, and while a spinner or other indefinite animation would probably be more correct, I prefer a horizontal progress bar.

Any ideas?

Comment: So you want the speed to be asymptotic?

Comment: I want the effect of repeatedly letting out half the water from the bathtub, never quite emptying it :)